# Automate task of searching for time periods

Tags: excel, loops, automation, excel-formula, vba

I want to automate the task of selecting different periods from a timeline to fill a daily schedule afterwards.

My list of data looks somehow like this and I'm trying to write a code so that Excel gets the first and the last times of each period (values different than 0)

```
12:00:28 AM,    0
12:15:30 AM,    0
12:30:30 AM,    0
12:45:30 AM,    0
01:00:30 AM,    0
01:15:30 AM,    68.2
01:30:30 AM,    19.8
01:45:30 AM,    17.2
02:00:30 AM,    16.1
02:15:30 AM,    15.3
02:30:30 AM,    15
02:45:30 AM,    14.6
03:00:30 AM,    14.6
03:15:30 AM,    0
03:30:30 AM,    0
03:45:30 AM,    0
04:00:30 AM,    0
04:15:30 AM,    59.4
04:30:30 AM,    29.7
04:45:30 AM,    21.2
05:00:30 AM,    17.8
05:15:30 AM,    12.1
05:30:29 AM,    0
05:45:30 AM,    0
06:00:30 AM,    0
06:15:30 AM,    0
06:30:30 AM,    0
06:45:30 AM,    0
07:00:29 AM,    0
07:15:30 AM,    0
07:30:30 AM,    0
07:45:30 AM,    0
08:00:30 AM,    0
```

Any ideas or comments on how to automate that?

Comment: first of all your data is not very self-explanatory, and the answer could be vastly different based on how you want to have it interpreted. is 12:00:28 AM meaning 12:00- 12:28? or is each comma spaced set its own time like twelve o'clock and twenty eight seconds? also, what methods have you tried?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear information. The first column refers to the sampling time (hh:mm:ss AM/PM), and the second one to the obtained value.
I'm not very experienced with programming, it might be simple to do it but I just can't seem to find the right way. I have tried to loop over the range but it just can identify the first period.
Thanks for your prompt response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `12:00:28 AM,` is in A2 and B1 is blank, you might flag the values in which I think you are interested with this formula in C2 copied down to suit:

```
=IF(OR(AND(B1=0,B2>0),AND(B2>0,B3=0)),"#","")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!
Using flags to select the values I want was exactly what I needed. My code works perfectly now

Comment: Yes, that is what I actually did. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you could use filters in excel to only display the ones that have values other than 0, and use formulas to obtain those values from a different area (perhaps vba would allow you to grab them from a non-excel file? but you will have to type the data somewhere anyway so perhaps this ability is not necessary )